# IndexOf element in array

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to get index from array of elements.

```
 var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('class'); //3 elements

 console.log(arr);
 output// [div.class.selected, div.class, div.class, item: function, namedItem: function]

 var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
 var selected_id = arr.indexOf(selected[0]);
```

The last line of code give me an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.
I also tried to add `toString()` and search, but the same error.

Answer (score 8):

It's because `arr` is a (live) NodeList not an array; what you want is, I think:

```
console.log([].indexOf.call(arr, selected[0]));
```

```js
 var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
 var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
 var selected_id = [].indexOf.call(arr, selected[0]);
 console.log(selected_id);
```

```html
<div class="class"></div><div class="class"></div><div class="class selected"></div><div class="class"></div>
```

The line:

```
var selected_id = [].indexOf.call(arr, selected[0]);
```

Uses the native `Array.prototype.indexOf()` method, supplying the `arr` as the `this` (basically using `arr` as the array on which the method is called), supplying `selected[0]` as the argument to be passed to the method, so it *sort of* gets applied as you called it yourself:

```
var selected_id = arr.indexOf(selected[0]);
```

but does it in a way that recognises the `indexOf()` method isn't available to the `NodeList` object (calling it in a legitimate way, and therefore preventing the error).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/document/getElementsByClassName).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: If you want to deal with an **HTMLCollection** and transform it into an javascript array.

Since **ES6**, it can be done with :

`var arr = Array.from ( yourHtmlCollection );`

And then you can call "indexOf" on it

`var index = arr.indexOf( anElementOfThisArray );`

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, but an `HTMLCollection`. Thus, it doesn't have array methods like `indexOf`. You need to explicitly call array methods with a `this` value of the `HTMLCollection` like this:

```
var selected_id = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(arr, selected[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `document.getElementsByClassName('class')` doesn't return an `Array`, but a `NodeList` which is an array-like object. You can turn an array-like object to an array by using:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
```